Issue with back buttom from native android code to flutter
I have an android library that have some native screens and features everything is working but issue is when i backPressed from native Activity then my flutter screen is reloaded but i want my flutter screen should be the last position
at my native Activity uses onbackpressed

I have tryied finish() in my nativeScreen but still getting the same issue. is there any other alternate options or suggestion please drop here.

here is my MainActivity for flutter to native launch SDK


import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import investwell.activity.SplashActivity
import investwell.sdk.MintSDK
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant
import org.json.JSONException
import org.json.JSONObject
import java.lang.Exception
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {

    private val CHANNEL = "mint-android-app"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        // Aligns the Flutter view vertically with the window.
//        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(getWindow(), false)

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            // Disable the Android splash screen fade out animation to avoid
            // a flicker before the similar frame is drawn in Flutter.
            splashScreen.setOnExitAnimationListener { splashScreenView -> splashScreenView.remove() }
        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // mintSDK Invoke

        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(FlutterEngine(this))
        flutterEngine?.dartExecutor?.binaryMessenger?.let {  MethodChannel(it,CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->

            if (call.method == "openMintLib") {
                try {
                    var domain =""
                    var sso =""
                    var fcm =""
                    val argumentsString: String? = call.arguments?.toString()
                    val tokenResponse = JSONObject(call.arguments.toString())
                    if (tokenResponse.toString().isEmpty()){
                        argumentsString.let { jsonString->
                            try {
                                val newResponse = JSONObject(jsonString)
                                domain = newResponse.optString("domain")
                                sso = newResponse.optString("ssoToken")
                                fcm = newResponse.optString("fcmToken")
                            }catch (e:Exception){e.printStackTrace()}
                        }
                    }else{
                        domain = tokenResponse.optString("domain")
                        sso = tokenResponse.optString("ssoToken")
                        fcm = tokenResponse.optString("fcmToken")
                    }
                    invokeSDK(sso,fcm,domain)
                    result.success("Success")
                }catch (e: JSONException) {
                    // Handle JSON parsing error
                    result.error("JSON Parsing Error", e.message, null)
                }
            } else {
                result.notImplemented()
            }
        } }

    }

    private fun invokeSDK(sso: String,fcmToken:String,domain:String,classWithPackage:String= "${this@MainActivity.packageName}.MainActivity") {
        val mintSdk = MintSDK(this@MainActivity)
        mintSdk.invokeMintSDK(sso,fcmToken,domain,classWithPackage)
    }

}



i am facing same issue but not found solutions
